# Maven can't resolve dependencies from Parent Module in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, maven-3, dependency-management

I have been trying to `clean install` several modules, all of which have the same parent module in Nexus however this has resulted in the same error across all of them from IntelliJ:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project com.child-module:child-artifact-id:1.0.0: Failure to find parent-group-id:parent-artifact-id:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.workplace.com/content/repositories/workplace-internal-snapshot/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updated are forced.`

Tried multiple resolutions from various StackOverflow answers including deleting the "_maven.repository" of missing artifact. I also attempted the forced `mvn clean install -U` and `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install` commands. I deleted everything in my Users/me/.m2/repository and reimport the jars. Settings.xml is in exact location and exact copy as my team members.

The imported parent pom is same as everybody else's so my local machine for some reason isn't updating/finding the dependency even after implementing the resolutions mentioned above. Where else in my local could I check that might cause this issue?

For reference this is on IntelliJ w Maven3.

Comment: Have you tried to run maven from OS terminal = what result do you get there?

Comment: Tried that as well, no success, same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this had to do with manual installation of Lombok that somehow also conflicted with seemingly unrelated packages.